# Is getting Par on Mighty Switch Force levels important?

Tags: mighty-switch-force

I am playing Mighty Switch Force, and so far I haven't gotten Par time on any of the levels.

Is it important at all? Does getting Par unlock anything? Should I go back and try until I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, all you get for beating ALL par times is Patricia in casual clothes on the title screen. Simply beating the game gives you the Mega Blaster.